# How to check if a SqlConnection is possible, and do something consequently?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, authentication

I have an ASP.NET solution that launch a website, with a login page.
Also, I have created many Sql server accounts that give access to the same databases.
I want that, when an user put his username & password in my login page, my app try to connect to Sql server using this username & password.

So I don't have a table with the usernames & passwords of the users in my database, but I have many SQL server accounts with theses usernames & passwords.
I hope I'm clear enough.

So, I want to know, when my app try to connect to Sql server, if the username & password that the user enters doesn't refer to any account, if we can display an error message.
So the user know that he enters his credentials incorrectly, and he can try to enter theml again.
Is it possible ?

Thanks for your help and have a nice day.

Comment: Why not just attempt the connection? A "login denied" message is clearly distinguishable from a "server unreachable" message or suchlike (specifically, if an `SqlException` is caught more details are available in the `Errors` property). Do note that, for security purposes, you will never be able to distinguish between login attempts with an incorrect password, and an attempt for an account that does not exist at all.

Comment: The "login denied" message will appear on the website ? Or will it appear on my code ? Because I need it to be on the website, so the user, that will not have access to the code, will see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I would think you can build the connectionstring up and then just add the username and password and then attempt to connect. You can encase it in a try catch block and if it fails you can display a message on the form or you can work out what the error from the try catch block is saying and display your own message.

Something like this

```
<add key="ConnectionString" value="server=serverName;database=database;User ID=username;password=password"/>
```

could be

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();

```
try
{
  string connectionString = @"<add key="""ConnectionString"" 
  value="""server=serverName;database=database;User ID="" + txtUsername.Text + """;password="" + txtPassword.Text +"""/>";

con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

con.Open();   
}
catch (exception ex)
{
    read ex.message
}
```

Then you can use the following to see if connection was sucessful

```
if (con.State = ConnectionState.Open)
{
  your code here...
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you, I will try something like that.